# Тема ICO. Как реализовать airdrop ( раздачу токенов всем пользователям) на платформе Waves?

Tags: token, exchange, bitcoin, ethereum

Есть готовый токен созданный на платформе Waves, как распределить часть токенов между всеми пользователями платформы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AirDrop на WavesPlatform очень интересная и недорогая штука для ICO! На самой платформе эта функция называется Масстранфер, она реализует отправку токенов на 100 адресов за раз. Масстрансфер стоит всего 0,001 волны плюс 0,0005 волны на одного получателя, то есть вы можете распределить токены на 1 000 адреса меньше, чем $3.

Ознакомительная информация тут https://blog.wavesplatform.com/how-to-conduct-your-airdrop-using-waves-29307cdff763

А техническая тут https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/technical-details/mass-transfer-transaction.html